# Converting report templates RPT/RDL to JRXML/Jasper Reports?

Tags: java, templates, crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I'm currently using Crystal Reports and I'd like to switch to Jasper. To ease the transition, I'd like to have a methodology for automatically or semi-automatically converting existing templates. This may involve one more more intermediate formats/applications/libraries, free or paid, open-source or proprietary - I'm just looking for something *possible*.

After some digging I found an application that can convert Crystal to SQL Reporting Services, Crystal Converter, but that's about it (there were also a bunch of dead projects and websites that no longer even exist). Does anyone here know of more existing software or libraries that can help me get this working? Can anyone experienced with the subject matter let me know exactly which parts I'll have to write myself, and what existing solutions to use to accomplish the others?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I can't ask anything more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry. Developing such a tool is against the Crystal Reports License Agreements, so you will never find one on the market.

But if you want to do it yourself, you can have a look at the [save()-Function of the ReportClientDocument](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi/ras/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/report/application/ReportClientDocument.html#save%28com.crystaldecisions.xml.serialization.XMLWriter,%20com.crystaldecisions.xml.serialization.XMLSerializationContext%29). It allows to XML-Serialize a report. Doing the conversion to Jasper is just an XSLT away ;).

Oh, please update me with the results of your work, I would love to reuse it :).

Comment: I had a look at this function for myself, but it never created anything. Anyone has an idea how to make this function work?

Comment: Marked as answer for "you will never find one on the market", which is the conclusion I previously arrived to. I'm afraid I can't help you either.